# No module named 'raven' while installing sentry in docker

Tags: django, sentry

ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'sentry': Cannot resolve    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler': No module    named 'raven'

Comment: error is : No module named raven . You need to install raven with `pip install raven `

Comment: I already install pip install raven but still got error...

Comment: Please format your "question" so that it can actually be read. Probably best to use the code format -- and then you need also to add the question, not just dump of log. Title should be title of your question, not story of what you're doing

Comment: Ok @JamesZ sorry I will format it.... =D

Comment: You don't need to add all that fluff to your title. Everyone understands that you need help, or advise what to do.

Comment: I noted @JamesZ

Comment: Did you add raven to your installed apps?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS += ('raven.contrib.django.raven_compat', ) Already add @devdob

Comment: Can you share your settings file?